# MapBox loads wrong map

Tags: ios, mapbox

I followed the installation steps from mapbox ios sdk. Then, i run my app in simulator and everything was right with the example map id into RMMapBoxSource.Although when i made a custom map in mapbox online and tried to load it into my app it always loads a map from Washighton DC city and not my custom map. Can anyone tell me whats going wrong with this? Here is the code from the controller that tries to load map:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    RMMapBoxSource *tileSource = [[RMMapBoxSource alloc] initWithMapID:@"hoya21.map-nkbz19y4"];

    RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:tileSource];

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to [mapbox.com](https://www.mapbox.com/), open up your map project, click the gear at the top of the window next to the map name and then check the box next to "Save current map position".

[image]